# Symfony class not found but the class is defined

Tags: php, symfony

I've created a class in symfony, the file path is

```
src/Project/MemberBundle/Document/EnumMemberType.php
```

and the file looks like this

```
<?php

namespace Project\MemberBundle\Document;

class EnumMemberType {

    const VIP = 'xxxxx';

}  // class - EnumMemberType
```

but when i try to get the constant in this class in another file using the code

```
$memberType = \Project\MemberBundle\Document\EnumMemberType::VIP
```

i got the error

> Attempted to load class "EnumMemberType" from namespace "Project\MemberBundle\Document".
>     Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

I really can't figure out why, the file name is the same with the class name, and it's under the right folder, and the file starts with `<?php`.

Can anyone see what else i'm missing? Thanks

Comment: Looks like class defined correctly. Can you show full error trace?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe problem with namespace. You can write in the header of another file:

```
use Project\MemberBundle\Document\EnumMemberType
```

and

```
$memberType = EnumMemberType::VIP;
```